# Apache POI - Criar documento word

Tags: apache-poi

gostaria de criar documento do Microsoft Word com programação, mas estou tendo dificuldade, pois sou iniciante em Java. Tentei começar com o exemplo do link a seguir "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_document.htm", mas não funcionou. Gostaria de preencher um formulário no browser e a partir daí, gerar um documento e colocá-lo em um compartilhamento na rede. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Obrigado